# unable to load my ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I'm kinda new to Linux and I went and made a dual boot with my win 11 machine and Ubuntu at first everything went good but I made something wrong while playing around with the system and it wouldn't boot up... So I thought well might reinstall the system so when I made that at first went really wierd because it wouldn't restart itself after the install it would be only a black screen with a white cursor on the side so after more than 30 min I force restarted it and now when I try to load the system it sends me to the GNU/GRUB terminal... I think it might be related to the secure boot because to set my GPU to work I've added a key before boot because it said something like I had to set one up otherwise the system will not recognize the board
Now I can't use the system at all only win 11...
Any ideias? I could delete all secure key variables but I don't know the consequences of that
Thanks in advance